# Javascript how to java read object created by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to loop for each test1, test2 ,test 3 .... and get the value
after colon.

i try the method on below

```
javascript:
    var totalResult = {};
    for (i = 1; i < b+1; i++) {
    totalResult["test"+i+""] = 1+ "," +2+ "," +3+ "," +4;
    }
    $("#result ").val(JSON.stringify(totalResult));

Java
        String result = {"test1":"1,2,3,4","test2":"1,2,3,4"};
```

actually what i really want to do is get all the value from a div, this div is having a set of input generated dynamically, i wanted to get all value and read it by java

```
<div class="customgroup">
<label>Mobile</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<select class="btn btn-primary customPrefix" id="phonenumberheader1" name = "phonenumberheader1">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
</select> 
</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control customMobileNo" placeholder="Mobile No" id="phonenumber1" name="phonenumber1">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you the post the HTML code with the inputs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also, this is Javascript, not Java.  They are about as similar as Car and Carpet.

Comment: @JoeC - Well, no. The question (poor as it is) is about reading a JavaScript-generated JSON object in Java, so it's more like the Carpet in the Car (or a Car on a Carpet).